# Grabbing a text from a web page in Cypress

Tags: typescript, text, cypress, cypress-file-upload

How can I grab a text from a Webpage in Cypress using Typescript.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want assert an exact text you can use:

```js
cy.get('selector').should('have.text', 'some text')
```

If you want assert an partial text you can use:

```js
cy.get('selector').should('include.text', 'some text')
```

If you want to save the text in a variable and use it later you can use aliases.

```js
cy.get('selector').invoke('text').as('text1')
//Some other commands
cy.get('@text1').then((text) => {
  cy.log(text) //Prints the text
})
```

If you want to Compare two texts, you can:

```js
cy.get('selector').invoke('text').then((text1) => {
  cy.get('selector').invoke('text').then((text2) => {
    expect(text1).to.equal(text2)
  })
})
```